# How to filter jq based on the key value?

Tags: json, jq

I am quite new with JQ library, I want to filter the json file using their name(eg. release-1),Then I want to return key value of the all commitId in the same object as the name.

My json file

```
{
   "releases":[
      {
         "name":[
            "release-1"
         ],
         "artifacts":[
            {
               "name":"pkg-1",
               "commitId":"523asdc3"
            },
            {
               "name":"pkg-2",
               "commitId":"523asdc3"
            },
            {
               "name":"pkg-3",
               "commitId":"523asdc3"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":[
            "release-2"
         ],
         "artifacts":[
            {
               "name":"pkg-3",
               "commitId":"523asdc3"
            },
            {
               "name":"pkg-4",
               "commitId":"523asdc3"
            },
            {
               "name":"pkg-5",
               "commitId":"523asdc3"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected Output

```
523asdc3
523asdc3
523asdc3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.releases[] | select(.name | index("release-1")) | .artifacts[].commitId
```

Will show each `commitId` where `name` contains ([`index()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example51)) `release-1`.

Result:

```
"523asdc3"
"523asdc3"
"523asdc3"
```

[JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BxFuRd43Vzt)

Answer (score 0):

.releases[]|select(.name|contains(["release-1"]))|.artifacts[].commitId

is another way.

.releases[]|select(.name[0] =="release-1")|.artifacts[].commitId

is yet another way.